# Run JUnit test from Java

Tags: java, junit

I would like running my `JUnit` test from Java.

I use :

```
JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
runner.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
runner.run(AdditionTest.class);
```

But I would like the name of the test, the result (`true` or `false`), the failure

How I have it?

Answer (score 2):

Read the [documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html)! [JUnitCore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html) returns a [Result](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Result.html) object when you call run(...). The result object has methods like `getFailures()`, `getRunTime()` and of course `wasSuccessful()`.

```
JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
runner.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
Result result = runner.run(AdditionTest.class);
boolean wasSuccessful = result.wasSuccessful();
System.out.println("tests were successful: " + wasSuccessful);
```

Comment: I have read the documentation; But how can I get the name of the test methods?

Comment: Well, you can get them directly from your test class via reflection. They are all annotated with @Test (or?).

Comment: For exemple I have :
    @Test
    public void rangeSize() {
        Assert.assertEquals(3, Lists.range(0, 2).size());
        Assert.assertEquals(5, Lists.range(-2, 2).size());
    }


And I would like display :
rangeSize : True
Or
rangeSize : failure : Error...